# How to install postgres-client 'psql' in AWS CloudShell permanently

Tags: postgresql, aws-cloudshell

I have successfully installed postgresql-client 'psql' in the AWS CloudShell.  When I close the instance and re-open it.  The installation is not there, I am getting "-bash: psql: command not found".

It seems like the installation is only for the sessions or instance.
How can I make it permanent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The postgresql (instance ) is installed in AWS RDS.